# Can a component of velocity be greater than the speed of light?

Tags: special-relativity, vectors, coordinate-systems, faster-than-light

Suppose a particle is travelling with a velocity ***v***. Can a component of this velocity(let's say the y-component) be greater than the speed of light ***c***?

Comment: no, because then the total speed would be greater than c.

Comment: It is trivial that since the norm of the velocity can't be greater than the speed of light, none of its component can be. Do you have any other confusion or a paradox that leads you to investigate this question?

Comment: Well, I was studying superluminal motion from Wikipedia. There is a concept where the apparent velocity was greater than the speed of light. I got confused between that and component of a velocity.

Here's the link: - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superluminal_motion

Answer (score 4):

No, because the total magnitude of the speed vector may not exceed the speed of light, and it is itself greater than the absolute value any of its component :

$$\vec{v}=$\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix} $$

Since:

$|x|=\sqrt{x^2}\le\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}=||\vec{v}||$

Physically, the norm may not exceed the speed of light $c$:
$$||\vec{v}||<c$$

Therefore $|x|<c$, $|y|<c$ and $|z|<c$

Comment: Well, I was studying superluminal motion from Wikipedia. There is a concept where the apparent velocity was greater than the speed of light. I got confused between that and component of a velocity. 

Here's the link: - en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superluminal_motion

It would be helpful if we can clear this doubt.

Comment: @QuamosM87 Those are indeed distinct questions. It looks like a good Stack Overflow question, as well. Why don't you post a new one/search for an existing one?